# Title disappears after returning from ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, back-button, uicontainerview

My `UIViewController` title disappears when returning from another `UIViewController`.

**My setup is as follows:**

```
UINavigationController -> 
RootViewSegue -> 
mainUIViewController -> 
ContainerView -> 
embedSegue -> 
UITableViewController -> 
pushSegue -> 
detailUIViewController
```

`mainUIViewController` loads correctly upon initial startup, including the `UITableViewController` that has been embedded in the `ContainerView`. The title for main `UIViewController` is shown.

When pressing the back button in detail `UIViewController`, the main `UIViewController` appears again, but the title bar has become blank.

`ViewDidAppear` is called on main `UIViewController` when pressing the back button. When querying inside `viewDidAppear` for `self.title`, the correct title is returned. This is the case on initial load and after returning to main `UIViewController`.

`self.navigationcontroller` seems to be nil however. Querying for it returns:

```
error: property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'mainViewController *'
```

I would like to know how to reach and set the now visible title bar?

Comment: How you set the title? from main storyboard or from code?

Comment: Yes, both from code and from storyboard, just to be sure.

Comment: can u please give clarification on view controller hierarchy ? How u r going to container view from main view ?

Comment: The containerview is a subview inside the mainUIViewController. I am using an embed Segue to link from the containerview to the child tableviewcontroller. from the UITableViewController I am using a push segue to get to the detailUIViewController.